# nice stationary process with discrete spectrum

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

I'd like to have an example of a stationary process $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ on a finite alphabet for which the shift $T$ is ergodic and has discrete spectrum, and for which there is a "nice" description of the law of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, for example a simple expression for the transition probabilities $\Pr(X_{n+1}=x \mid X_m, m\leq n)$.